# Convert data/time string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a date/time string `"06/14/2016 07:00 PM"` to a `Time` object under the PST time zone. I want the result to be `Tue, 14 Jun 2016 19:00:00 PDT -07:00`.

I tried the following:

```
t = "06/14/2016 07:00 PM"
r = Time.strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p").in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
```

The time comes back as `Tue, 14 Jun 2016 17:00:00 PDT -07:00`. Any ideas?

Comment: What time zone are you in? It seems as if your computer thinks you're in the central time zone.

Comment: Also, I'm getting that `in_time_zone` is an undefined method.

Comment: @EliSadoff I added the rails tag as that is a rails method

Answer (score 1):

This code to me works properly, but there are two possible issues that are giving you the wrong result:

1. **You are not in the pacific time zone** (or at least not according to your computer): You can test this by running `r = Time.strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")`, and then printing the result of `r`. I'm willing to wager that it outputs
   `Tue, 14 Jun 2016 19:00:00 CDT -05:00`
2. **You are using ruby and not rails**, `in_time_zone` is a method only in rails. If you try to use it in `ruby` it will not work.

Comment: You can use ActiveSupport in non-Rails projects if you want methods like `in_time_zone`.